# Change Selected Image Visabilty Winrt

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to change the image visibility  in a list box selected item then change it back when its unselected

[image]

I have tried searching but I cant find anything that lets me change the visibility, and anything I have found doesn't explain how to change an item after its deselected.

any help would be great, thanks

Comment: It's easiest if you bind the visibility to a property of the object that uses a visibility converter.

Comment: @WiredPrairie can you please show an example or provide a link to one thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement DataTemplateSelector [following this tutorial](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-8---winrt-datatemplateselector-change-the-color-of-listboxitem-depending-on-condition) or [this tutorial link](https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/data-template-selector-in-windows-8-metro-xaml-app/). Both these provide source code or in other way use ***INotifyPropertyChanged*** interface for this. create a class which provides text and image visibility and implement the interface like this.

```
    class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public string _txt{get;set;}
private Visibility _placeholderVisbile { get; set; }
        public Visibility PlaceholderVisible
        {
            get { return _placeholderVisbile; }
            set { _placeholderVisbile = value; OnPropertyChanged("PlaceholderVisible"); }
        }
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and on Selection Changed event make it collapsed and all other visible. Though try implementing DataTemplateSelector more suitable for your problem. Hope it helps.